# c++ exception message in messagebox

Tags: exception, c++-cx

Seems simple but can't find the solution.

I want something like this

```
catch (Exception^ ex)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, ex->ToString(),  "", MB_OK);
}
```

But it says Plattform::string ^ is incompatible with LPCSTR.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Platform::String is .NET class, which is of course is not compatible with good old `char*`.

To fix this you need to do 2 things.

First, convert `Platform::String` to `wchar_t*`, since it's unicode string. Use method [`Data()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh825860.aspx)

Second, use MessageBoxW, since we are working with unicode, not ANSI.

Resulting code should look like this:

```
MessageBoxW(NULL, ex->ToString()->Data(),  "", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.
(used MessageBoxW(NULL, ex->ToString()->Data(), NULL, MB_OK); to be exact)

Comment: Something went horribly wrong in this Q+A, Platform::String is **not** a .NET class.  It is the language projection for an HSTRING, a WinRT type.  Not a managed bone in its body.  Using MessageBox() in an app that targets WinRT is wrong, use Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog instead.

Comment: Not that it matters much (as @HansPassant already pointed out, that this is **not** an answer), but you cannot pass `""` to `MessageBoxW` either.